# Referencing a custom composer package in Slim PHP

Tags: php, class, namespaces, composer-php, slim

I'm trying to figure out how to reference a custom class using composer

my composer.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "adtools_api",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "qz/adtools_middleware",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "repo-name",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
   "require": {
       "slim/slim": "2.*",
       "qz/adtools_middleware": "src/"
   }
}
```

and the folder structure looks like this:

```
app
    routes
    vendor
        composer
        qz
            adtools_middleware
                src
                    hello-world.php
        slim
    composer.json
    index.php
```

I'm trying to reference the hello-world.php file which looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace HelloWorld;

class SayHello
{
    public static function world()
    {
        return 'Hello World, Composer!';
    }
}

?>
```

In the index.php file I'm trying to reference the class like this:

```
$hello = new HelloWorld\SayHello();
```

but getting an error telling me "Fatal error: Class 'HelloWorld\SayHello' not found in..."

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the `autoload` inside the `vendor` folder and see if your `HelloWorld` namespace is loaded?

If not, you may need to add `autoload` attribute to your `composer.json` file, like this

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"HelloWorld": "qz/adtools_middleware/src/"}
},
```

to load the `HelloWorld` namespace in your project